# Elucidation needed in protein dynamics

Tags: resource-recommendations, biophysics, molecular-dynamics

I'm reading some papers about protein dynamic, stability and energy landscape. Switching from paper to paper I'm encountering different term used for talking about protein movements, for example: α- and β-fluctuations, structural relaxations, translational motions, large scale motions, slaving etc.
I tried to look in reviews or in textbook but I struggled to find an ordered and precise nomenclature for proteins movements. So, if someone could help me in understanding a little bit more about protein dynamics terminology and moreover if can suggest a textbook or a review that explain and clarify this argument.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what papers? so I can read them as well :)

Comment: Hey, I have found this paper that is very clear: A unified model of protein dynamics, Hans Frauenfelder et al. 2009. PNAS.

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_helix  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_sheet